# How to properly keep track of and reset a score

Tags: python, variables

I'm brand spanking new to python, and I'm trying to make a simple game based on russian roulette. The problem is it doesn't seem to be keeping track of the score properly. No matter what I try, it either keeps the score at 0, or doesn't reset. Is there a less dumb way to go about this? trying to get the bare bones down so sorry it looks a bit weak.

```
from random import *

score = 0

def life_death():
    
        life = randint(1, 6)
        death = randint(1, 6)
        if life == death:

                print('you lose')
                play_again()
        else:

                print('congrats')
                
def play_again():

        ans = input('Play again? y/n')
        if ans == 'y':

                score = 0
        else:

                quit()
#Main game

while True:

        life_death()
        score = score + 1
        if score == 5:

                print('You win')
                play_again()
```

Comment: For your future reference, the "code" markers in SO are three backticks, not three apostrophes.  On US keyboards, that's on the same key as tilde.

Comment: If you intend to change a global variable, you must declare that, otherwise Python assumes it's a local.  Add `global score` at the start of `play_again`.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing local and global variables. When you defined `score` first, it was a local variable. When you reset it in `play_again()` and updated it in `life_death()`, it was in the function's local scope. For instance:

```
from random import *

score = 0

def play_again():
    global score
    ans = input('Play again? y/n')
    if ans == 'y':

            score = 0
    else:

            quit()
def life_death():

    life = randint(1, 6)
    death = randint(1, 6)
    if life == death:

            print('you lose')
            print(f'Score: {score}')
            play_again()
    else:

            print('congrats')
            
while True:

    life_death()
    score = score + 1
    if score == 5:

            print('You win')
            
            play_again()
```

I would recommend using everything in the local scope, though. For example, defining another function `roulette()` that creates a local variable `score`.

@TimRoberts: Below is an implementation using only local variables:

```
from random import *


def play_again():
    ans = input('Play again? y/n')
    if  ans == 'y':
        roulette()
    else:
        quit()
def roulette(score = 0):
    if not score == 5:
        if randint(1,6)==1:
            print("You lose!")
            print(f"Final Score: {score}")
            play_again()
        else:
            print("   Congrats! You did not lose.")
            print(f"   Score: {score+1}")
            roulette(score+1)
    else:
        print("You win the game!")
        play_again()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    roulette()
```

Comment: _defining another function ... that creates a local variable_ -- What earthly good does that do?  `score` needs to be a shared between the global level and the functions somehow.